# How to add a string to a pre-existing string in a C# array

Tags: c#

I am supposed to create an array of strings in C#, Ask the Console for a random word, and that random word will get added to the end of every string in the array. In a second loop it will print the results It's not adding another index to the array, but adding to the pre-existing string through a loop.

```
string[] strArray = { "text", "what" };
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in some text");
            string response = Console.ReadLine();

            foreach (string resp in strArray)
                
            {
                //*tring joined = string.Join(strArray, response);*/
                //strArray[resp] = strArray[resp] + Console.ReadLine();
                //strArray = strArray.Append(response).ToArray();
                //strArray = resp + response;
                //string resp2 = resp + response;
                strArray[resp] = resp + response;
            }

            foreach (string i in strArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

That is currently what I have. Everything in // are things I have tried. If the user types in "hello" for example, it should print "text hello", "what hello" to the console

Comment: You can't do that with a `foreach` loop, AFAIK. Use a `for(int i = 0;...` style loop instead.

Comment: I was using the wrong type of loop to begin with. I have figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: You can do it in one loop will help with complexity since you now will on have to O(n).             string[] strArray = { "text", "what" };
            for (int i = 0; i < strArray .Length; i++)
            {
                strArray[i] = strArray[i] + toAdd;
                Console.WriteLine(strArray[i]);
            }

Comment: If the strings are going to be modified a lot, have you considered using `StringBuilder`, and converting to `string` after all changes have been made?

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] strArray = { "text", "what" };

string response = "_X";

// Be warning, black magic!
foreach (ref string resp in strArray.AsSpan())
{
    resp += response;
}

foreach (string s in strArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

For more information, see the [foreach statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-foreach-statement) article.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
{
    strArray[i] += response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
strArray[resp] = resp + response;
```

`resp` is *not a valid index for the array*. This shouldn't even compile.

If you need to update the array, you need to know the index. That means looping through the array by index with a `for` loop rather than by value with a `foreach` loop:

```
for (int s=0;i<strArray.Length; s++)        
{
    strArray[s] = strArray[s] + response;
}
```