Iterating through a collection and changing the collection as you go
I'm trying to update a collection with incoming values based on conditions.  I know you cannot modify a collection as you iterate through it so I created a copy of it and update it outside of the foreach loop.
No such luck as I get that same "Collection was Modified..." error my second time through the loop.  Since the modification is done outside of the foreach loop I don't see why it's a problem.  Is there a standard way to do this?
List<ThisModel> retVal = [];

 // initialize retVal with some values

List<ThisModel> retVal_copy = [];
retVal_copy = retVal;


foreach(ThisModel item in retVal_copy)
{
   if(some_condition)
   {
     //initialize a new item
     retVal.Add(new_item)
   }
}

 retVal_copy= retVal;
}


retVal_copy = retVal; is not a copy, it's the same list.

This question is similar to: How do I clone a generic list in C#?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The following may be of interest: for.

Try to use ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76177303/5045688

You didn't actually make a copy of the collection. You made a copy of the reference to the collection. But both references point to the same object.
The way to solve this problem is create a new collection with the items you need.
var newCollection = new List<ThisModel>();
foreach(ThisModel item in oldCollection)
{
    if(some_condition(item))
    {
        newCollection.Add(item)
    }
}
return newCollection;

Or, with LINQ, you can shorten it like this:
return oldCollection.Where( item => some_condition(item) ).ToList();

If you need to update the old collection, update the reference to point at the new collection when you're done:
oldCollection = newCollection;

Or, if you absolutely need to keep the original object instance, clear it out and reload it:
oldCollection.Clear();
oldCollection.AddRange(newCollection);


But that doesn't change the oldCollection.  I need it to dynamically update each time it gets to the loop

I've edited my answer so you can update the old collection.

It can be like this:
List<ThisModel> retVal = [];

 // initialize retVal with some values

List<ThisModel> retVal_copy = [];


foreach(ThisModel item in retVal)
{
   if(some_condition)
   {
     //initialize a new item
     retVal_copy.Add(new_item)
   }
}

 retVal.AddRange(retVal_copy);
}

The solution creates the new temporary collection which joins the initial collection then.

If you don't want to copy any part of the collection (e.g. if the collection is quite large) you can use for loop instead of foreach:
int size = retVal.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  ThisModel item = retVal[i];

  if (some_condition) {
    //initialize a new item
    retVal.Add(new_item);
  } 
}

